# rxjava2 for load testing inconsistencies as result of onComplete event

Tags: java, rx-java2, load-testing

There is code that is supposed to do the load testing form some function that performs the http call (we call it `callInit` here) and collects some data in the `LoaTestMetricsData`:

> - the collected responses
> - and the total duration of the execution.

```
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.Scheduler;
import io.reactivex.Single;
import io.reactivex.observers.TestObserver;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject;
import io.reactivex.subjects.Subject;
import io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.greaterThanOrEqualTo;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.lessThan;

public class TestRx {

    @Test
    public void loadTest() {

        int CALL_N_TIMES = 10;
        final long CALL_NIT_EVERY_MILLISECONDS = 100;

        final LoaTestMetricsData loaTestMetricsData = loadTestHttpCall(
                                                            this::callInit,
                                                            CALL_N_TIMES,
                                                            CALL_NIT_EVERY_MILLISECONDS
                                                            );

        assertThat(loaTestMetricsData.responseList.size(), is(equalTo(Long.valueOf(CALL_N_TIMES).intValue())));

        long errorCount = loaTestMetricsData.responseList.stream().filter(x -> x.getStatusCode() != 200).count();

        long executionTime = loaTestMetricsData.duration.getSeconds();


        //assertThat(errorCount, is(equalTo(0)));

        assertThat(executionTime , allOf(greaterThanOrEqualTo(1L),lessThan(3L)));

    }

    // --

    private Single<Response> callInit() {
        try {
            return Single.fromCallable(() -> {

                System.out.println("...");
                sleep(1000);
                Response response = new RestAssuredResponseImpl();
                return response;
            });

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // --

    private LoaTestMetricsData loadTestHttpCall(final Supplier<Single<Response>> restCallFunction, long callnTimes, long callEveryMilisseconds) {

        long startTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

        final LoaTestMetricsData loaDestMetricsData = new LoaTestMetricsData();

        final AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);

        final TestObserver<Response> testObserver = new TestObserver<Response>() {
            public void onNext(Response response) {
                loaDestMetricsData.responseList.add(response);
                super.onNext(response);
            }
            public void onComplete() {
                loaDestMetricsData.duration = Duration.ofMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeMillis);
                super.onComplete();
            }
        };


        final Subject<Response> subjectInitCallResults = PublishSubject.create(); // Memo: Subjects are hot so if you don't observe them the right time, you may not get events. Thus: subscribe first then emit (onNext)

        final Scheduler schedulerIo = Schedulers.io();

    subjectInitCallResults
            .subscribeOn(schedulerIo)
            .subscribe(testObserver); // subscribe first


        final Observable<Long> source = Observable.interval(callEveryMilisseconds, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).take(callnTimes);

        source.subscribe(x -> {
            final Single<Response> singleResult = restCallFunction.get();

            singleResult
                    .subscribeOn(schedulerIo)
                    .subscribe( result -> {

                        int count = atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();

                        if(count == callnTimes) {
                            subjectInitCallResults.onNext(result); // then emit
                            subjectInitCallResults.onComplete();
                        } else {
                            subjectInitCallResults.onNext(result);
                        }


                    });
        });


        testObserver.awaitTerminalEvent();
        testObserver.assertComplete();
        testObserver.assertValueCount(Long.valueOf(callnTimes).intValue()); // !!!

        return loaDestMetricsData;

    }



}
```

The: LoaTestMetricsData is defined as:

```
public class LoaTestMetricsData {
    public List<Response> responseList = new ArrayList<>();
    public Duration duration;
}
```

**Sometimes** test fails with this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Value counts differ; expected: 10 but was: 9 (latch = 0, values = 9, errors = 0, completions = 1)
Expected :10 
Actual   :9 (latch = 0, values = 9, errors = 0, completions = 1)
<Click to see difference>
```

If someone could tell me why?

As is some of the subjectInitCallResults.onNext() has not been executed, or consumed. But why.. I understand that PublishSubject is hot observable, thus I subscribe for the events before emitting/onNext anything to it.

**UPDATE:**

What would fix it, is this ugly code, that would wait for the subject to fill up:

```
    while(subjectInitCallResults.count().blockingGet() != callnTimes) {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
   ..
   testObserver.awaitTerminalEvent();
```

But is the proper / better way of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using a `subscribeOn` with a `PublishSubject` and also driving it from a background thread so there is a chance onNext values go unobserved. First try with `UnicastSubject` to see if you get all expected items that way. If not, double check the code that is supposed to create 10 items.

Comment: Put an UPDATE. UnicastSubject did help. Eventually if to wait for the expected count, it fills with 10 values. But it's not nice code (see the update). I guess due to the background I thread, but I need them to run things in parallel for the load resting purpose.

Comment: There is a test method that hides such ugliness: [`awaitCount`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/BaseTestConsumer.html#awaitCount-int-).

Comment: it blocks existing thread and all stops. it will go with ugliness for now.